# remove part of a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

I have a string returned from a source that could be ...

```
'an unknown char count (more chars here of however many) then some more chars of unknown count'
```

I want to remove anything inside the `( )` including the brackets, anything before and after need to stay, which method will give me that result?

Tried a few ideas but getting nowhere

Comment: _TL;DR_ `str.replace(/\(.*?\)/, '')`